# Using preg_replace to truncate URL

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am working on code for a shout box, and I have added the following codes to handle URLs:

```
$shout_message = preg_replace('"\b(http://\S+)"', '<a href="$1"target="_blank">$1</a>', $shout_message);

$shout_message = preg_replace('#^ (?>((?:.*:/+)?[^/]+/.{1})) .{4,} (.{8})$ #x','$1...$2', $shout_message);
```

The first line identifies the URL and creates a hyperlink and the second truncates the URL For example, when submitted, (2nd / in http:// is removed since I can't post more than 2 links)

> http:/www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=truncate+url+php&oq=truncate+url&gs_l=hp.1.2.0j0i22i30l3.0.0.1.12.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c..7.psy-ab.lWUgfxOY55k&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.eWU&fp=b2f671f2a036cfc1&biw=1600&bih=780

becomes

> http:/www.google.com/#...=780

Both codes are working properly for the most part. However, if someone types and additional message after entering the URL, the hyperlink still works, but the message becomes part of the truncated string For example, if

> http:/www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=truncate+url+php&oq=truncate+url&gs_l=hp.1.2.0j0i22i30l3.0.0.1.12.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c..7.psy-ab.lWUgfxOY55k&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.eWU&fp=b2f671f2a036cfc1&biw=1600&bih=780
>   check this out.

is typed, then the truncated string appears as

> http:/www.google.com/#...his out.

Is there anything I can add that will help my code only truncate what is part of the URL and leave the trailing text alone?

Comment: Have you considered using other ways for achieving the same thing, like [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url)?

Comment: you could also [split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) the string then use the first array element

Comment: I have tried parse_url, but I can't get the coding correct. I get "Warning: parse_url() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given" so there must be something I'm missing.